# Login view controller don't want to dismiss after sign in

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, access-token

I want to ask I have a sign in view controller who don't want to dismiss after correctly add email and password. but when I try the simulator for the first time the sign in is working and directing to me to my home controller, but after I sign out. and try to sign in again, then the sign in not dismissing my sign in view controller. how is that possible? at first is working later on is not working, here I show you my code.

```
// this is my sign out button
    @objc private func handleSignOut() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Log Out".localized(), style: .destructive, handler: { (_) in

            self.progressHUD.show(in: self.view)
            ProfileServices.shared.signOutUser { success in

                if success {
                    self.progressHUD.dismiss(animated: true)
                    let signInVC = SigninViewController()
                    self.present(signInVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    self.progressHUD.textLabel.text = "Error"
                    self.progressHUD.dismiss(afterDelay: 0.4)
                }
            }
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel".localized(), style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

// this is my sign out function in ProfileServices.shared
    func signOutUser(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        AF.request(API_URL.AUTHENTICATION.LOGOUT, method: .delete, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: HEADERS, interceptor: nil).responseData { (dataResponse) in

            if dataResponse.error == nil {
                let domain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
                UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: domain)
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                UserDefaults.removeToken()

                completion(true)
            } else {
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }

// this is my sign in route in my sign in view controller
    func routeToMainView(_ data: SigninModel.Response) {
        let school = UserDefaults.getSelectedSchool()
        guard let schools = data.schools?.schools else { return }

        if let selectedSchool = school, let selected = schools.first(where: { $0.id == selectedSchool.id}) {
            UserDefaults.saveSelectedSchool(data: selected)
            let vc = MainViewController()
            self.viewController?.navigationController?.setViewControllers([vc], animated: true)
        } else {
            if schools.count > 1 {
                let vc = SwitchSchoolViewController()
                self.viewController?.navigationController?.setViewControllers([vc], animated: true)
            } else {
                guard let selected = schools.first else { return }
                UserDefaults.saveSelectedSchool(data: selected)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let vc = MainViewController()
                    self.viewController?.navigationController?.setViewControllers([vc], animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }

// this is in my appDelegate
    var root: UIViewController?
        root = SigninViewController()
        if UserDefaults.getToken() != nil {
            root = MainViewController()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In logout you need to dissmiss the presented viewController.

inplace :

```
let signInVC = SigninViewController()
self.present(signInVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

you need to use:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or pop if you will use Push.

Comment: if I dismiss the present it will not direct to SigninViewController right? since the log out is in my profile tab, if I dismiss it will bring me back to profile tab @AnilKumar

Comment: So you can do one more thing set signinViewController again as a root view controller in logout click.


let signInVC = SigninViewController() 
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow.rootViewController = signInVC

Comment: >self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    
                    let signInVC = SigninViewController()
                    
                    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = signInVC
                    
                    self.present(signInVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

I did it like this but it still not dismiss the sign in controller @AnilKumar

Comment: no addition code required only do like this 







..
let signInVC = SigninViewController() UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = signInVC

Comment: then what about dismiss you were refer to than? my present is not matter right? or I have to delete it, since when log out it still need to present sign in view controller

Comment: yeah now no need of dismiss and present code just set above code only.